# How to change back color on multiple buttons with extra button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a lot of buttons on page. Every button has white color as background color, and when I click on button it changes color to yellow.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(((Button)sender).BackColor != Color.Red)
    {((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Yellow;}
}
```

With one extra button I want to change the backcolors that are yellow to red. How to do this?
I know it can be done like this:

```
protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Button1.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
    { Button1.BackColor = Color.Red; }
    if (Button2.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
    { Button2.BackColor = Color.Red; }          
}
```

but I need a quicker way, so I don't have to write for every button specially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// name of the placeholder . In this case all controls are in `<form id="form1" runat="server" />` so i have put `form1.Controls`.

```
foreach (var item in form1.Controls)
        {
            if (item is Button)
            {
                if (((Button)item).BackColor == Color.Red)
                {
                    ((Button)item).BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
            }
        }
```

LINQ QUERY CAN BE WRITTEN AS

```
 foreach (Button item in form1.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(item => (item).BackColor == Color.Red))
        {
            (item).BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
```

Comment: @Servy: I have added LINQ version as well :)

Comment: I would add a few line breaks in there, and you don't need to wrap `item` in parenthesis when it's by itself, but those are just aesthetic changes.  Also you should be changing the color to Yellow, not Red.

Comment: Or I am using it wrong, or it doesn't work. Just to make sure, first part of code I posted is OK for me, it changes the clicked button backcolor to yellow. Then when I click that extra button it should change the backcollor of buttons that are yellow to red.

Comment: I added your code in and it doesn't do anything. For me my first part, protected void Button1_Click , is OK and it works.
I need help with this part, protected void Button7_Click. It works, but I will have about 50 buttons, and I need a way not to write for every one specially

Comment: @user1892380: just replace page.Controls with form1.Controls. In case you have different <form id=***> then put that

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the edit. Place all your buttons in a PlaceHolder. And you can call this code at PageLoad.

```
    foreach (Control item in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
    {
        if(item.GetType()== typeof(Button))
        {
            Button btn = (Button)item;
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(FunctionName);
        }

    }


protected void FunctionName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //You code here to change colors
    Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't compare the type as a string, you should use the type system that you can and compare it to `Button` as a type.

Comment: As I commented to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13806371/1159478), you can use `OfType` to do this more simply.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(((Button)sender).BackColor != Color.Red)
        {((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Yellow;}
    }

    protected void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is Button && (Button)sender != control && ((Button)control).BackColor == Color.Yellow)
            {
                ((Button)control).BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you iterating through the entire `Controls` collection when the button is passed to you already through `sender`?  Also, anytime this is called it will result in the back color being red, it won't toggle.

Comment: I thought he wanted only one button that was marked red at any given time. I have updated my answer @Servy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Javascript answer, in case you want to avoid the PostBack:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function changeColor() {

            var items = document.getElementById("buttons").getElementsByTagName("input");

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].style.background == "red")
                    items[i].style.background = "yellow";
                else
                    items[i].style.background = "red";
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="buttons">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" BackColor="Red" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" BackColor="Red" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" BackColor="Red" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" BackColor="Red" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button" BackColor="Red" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Click Me" BackColor="Red" OnClientClick="return changeColor()" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck!